# How to validate checkboxes using jquery validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery (jQuery validation plugin) to validate some inputs and make sure input fields are not empty. I have some checkbox inputs alongside select and other input elements. All the other validations are working and append some html to request the user to enter the required inputs.

The validation for checkboxes isn't working however -- no warning is printed on the webpage if no checkbox is selected.
How can I make checkboxes validation work in the code below please?

```js
$("#the-form").validate({
      rules: {
        'food_item[]': {
          required: true,
          minlength: 1,
        },
        select_event: {
          required: true,
        },
     }
 })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <form id="the-form">    
<div class="dropdown-menu w-100 p-5" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" id="the_things">

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between
             border-bottom py-5">
    <label for="one_thing">One thing</label>
    <input name="food_item[]" type="checkbox" class="dropdown-item w-25" id="one_thing" value="Item One">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between
             border-bottom py-5">
    <label for="second_thing">Second thing</label>
    <input name="food_item[]" type="checkbox" class="dropdown-item w-25" id="second_thing" value="Item two">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between
             border-bottom py-5">
    <label for="third_thing">Third thing</label>
    <input name="food_item[]" type="checkbox" class="dropdown-item w-25" id="third_thing" value="Item three">
  </div>
</div>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-outline-danger bg-light-danger d-block 
            font-weight-bolder my-8" 
    id="">Continue</button>    

<script src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a terribly good description of an error. What do you expect to happen that isn't? What is happening that you expect to happen? Please include a [mre], with links to the necessary scripts involved. Note that  currently there is a syntax error in the code because the `rules` property is missing its ending bracket `}` (or the object passed into `validate` is, whichever you prefer).

Comment: @HereticMonkey ending braces added now. Many thanks.

Comment: Still needs a `script` with a source for the jQuery validation plugin. Click "Run code snippet" and you'll see the error.

Comment: The other question is, what does it mean for a checkbox to be "required"? The only valid states for checkboxes are checked or not checked. If a user has left a checkbox unchecked, is that not fulfilling the "required"-ness?